# Implementation of synchronization primitives over HTML5 local storage

Tags: html, synchronization, local-storage

Consider a scenario where a browser has two or more tabs pointing to the same origin. Different event loops of the different tabs can lead to race conditions while accessing local storage and the different tabs can potentially overwrite each other's changes in local storage.

I'm writing a web application that would face such race conditions, and so I wanted to know about the different synchronization primitives that could be employed in such a scenario.

Comment: [Here is an article you should read.](http://balpha.de/2012/03/javascript-concurrency-and-locking-the-html5-localstorage/)

Comment: [Also see this section of the spec.](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/#threads) Browsers that allow local storage to change in a way unpredictable to a thread of execution are broken according to that spec.

Comment: @Pointy I've already read the article, and also [this one](http://blog.fastmail.fm/2012/11/26/inter-tab-communication-using-local-storage/) by FastMail. As far as the spec goes, I guess that guarantees that the individual read and write operations on local storage would be atomic. Even if that guarantee is given, the race conditions I mentioned would still occur.

Comment: The intent of the "local storage mutex" is that once a thread of execution (a JavaScript event loop) obtains the mutex, *it keeps it until the end of the event loop*.

Comment: @Pointy I'm not so well read on the workings of the event loop. What do you exactly mean by the **end** of event loop? I thought the event loop contains an event queue from which it reads indefinitely (until the tab is closed). So, in that sense, I'm confused as to what exactly is meant by the **end** of an event loop.

Comment: Well it may be moot anyway because apparently WebKit doesn't follow the spec. I'll add an answer because it's hard to type a good explanation in a comment :)

Answer (score 4):

My reading of [the relevant W3C spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/#threads), and the [comment](http://balpha.de/2012/03/javascript-concurrency-and-locking-the-html5-localstorage/#post-956858745) from Ian Hickson at the end of [this blog post on the topic](http://balpha.de/2012/03/javascript-concurrency-and-locking-the-html5-localstorage/), suggests that what's *supposed* to happen is that a browser-global mutex controls access to each domain's `localStorage`. Each separate "thread" (see below for what I'm fairly confident that means) of JavaScript execution must attempt to acquire the storage mutex (if it doesn't have it already) whenever it examines local storage. Once it gets the mutex, *it doesn't give it up* until it's completely done.

Now, what's a *thread*, and what does it mean for a thread to be *done*?  The only thing that makes sense (and the only thing that's really consistent with Hixie's claim that the mutex makes things "completely safe") is that a *thread* is JavaScript code in some browser context that's been initiated by some event. (Note that one possible event is that a `<script>` block has just been loaded.) The nature of JavaScript in the browser in general is that code in a `<script>` block, or code in a handler for any sort of event, runs until it stops; that is, runs to the end of  the `<script>` body, or else runs until the event handler returns.

So, given that, what the storage mutex is supposed to do is to force all shared-domain scripts to block upon attempting to claim the mutex when one of their number already has it. They'll block until the owning thread is done — until the `<script>` tag code is exhausted,  or until the event handler returns. That behavior would achieve this guarantee from the spec:

> Thus, the length attribute of a Storage object, and the value of the various properties of that object, cannot change while a script is executing, other than in a way that is predictable by the script itself.

However, it appears that WebKit-based browsers (Chrome and Safari, and probably the Android browser too, and now maybe Opera?) don't bother with the mutex implementation, which leaves you in the situation that drove you to ask the question. If you're concerned with such race conditions (a perfectly reasonable attitude), then you can use either the locking mechanism suggested in the blog post (by someone who does, or did, work for Stackoverflow :) or else implement a version counting system to detect dirty writes. (*edit* — now that I think about it, an RDBMS-style version mechanism would be problematic, because there'd *still* be a race condition checking the version!)