# Atomically get and set html5 localStorage

Tags: html, local-storage, atomic

I have a (stringified) list stored in HTML5 localStorage and want to append several items to it with different asynchronous callbacks. Therefore I am looking for a way to atomically get and set an item in localStorage in order to avoid race conditions. Is such a thing possible?

Comment: This question seems to have good thoughts on the topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22274688/implementation-of-synchronization-primitives-over-html5-local-storage

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that this is not necessary as javascript is single threaded by nature. So as long as `get` and `set` are in the same callback everything should be fine

Comment: That only protects you if there is only one tab. If you have multiple tabs you could still easily encounter a race condition.